# Developer workflow for tensorflow/tfx

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, minio, kubeflow, tfx

I'm trying to improve my workflow for supervised learning in the tf ecosystem, and was wondering if anyone has encountered/solved this problem.

I'm able to get a fully functional pipeline to execute in LocalDagRunner, however, because of this particular runner being designed for toy examples (from a memory perspective), I hit the limits that I wouldn't otherwise hit with the design of keras/beam.  So I'm trying to move to other Dag Runners, with the idea of doing some amount of local development, and then switching to vertex when I need big scale.

With that in mind, I know Kubeflow just came out with a major release (v2).  Running a tfx pipeline requires persistent storage that's accessible across the components.  How is this problem solved in Kubeflow?  I tried setting up minio but ran into some issues.

Looking forward to any advice anyone might have.  Thank you!

Pritam